# Why do the dolls attack everyone on the LOCUS SOLUS ship?

Tags: plot-explanation, ghost-in-the-shell-2

In *Ghost in the Shell 2: Innocence* Batou infiltrates a factory-ship owned by LOCUS SOLUS, while Togusa is hacking it externally. In the end, the dolls produced on the ship are activated and attack everyone, including the security and technical staff (albeit only the first group is explicitly shown being under attack).

Why are the dolls attacking everyone?

Looking at the description from Wikipedia, it seems there was a virus:

> Resolved to gather material evidence, Batou infiltrates the LOCUS SOLUS headquarters ship while Togusa remotely hacks its security systems using an unaware Kim as a proxy. The ship's security becomes aware of the hacking and retaliates with a virus that fries Kim's cyberbrain. **Simultaneously, a hidden virus loads a combat program into the production-line gynoids, causing them to attack everyone aboard.** As Batou fights to the ship's center, the Major then appears by controlling a gynoid remotely, helping Batou fight the gynoids and hack the ship's security.

Is it ever explained who installed this virus and why did it activate when it did? I'm thinking it was Kim (when he's fried a message appears on Togusas computer), but it's never explicitly stated... And if it was Kim, then why would he do this? As far as defense mechanisms go, this virus seems like a terrible idea.

The only idea I have is that it was revenge-based insurance. Kim was a security expert, and the virus could be his idea of effectively making everybody lose in case of his death - the ship becomes a floating death-trap filled with killer dolls. If LOCUS SOLUS would want to use the ship afterwards they'd need to spend a lot of resources cleaning that mess up...

Comment: IMO, when the hypothetical cost of resources of an adversary are so willfully abandoned for the sake of quelling an action that a protagonist seeks to impose it usually means that the movie needs a thrill scene. It does, however, make sense that the cost of loss (mess) for the operator of the ship is less than or equal to the cost of loss of being outed. It makes sense that Kim would be originator/creator of the virus, since he's a ghost hacker and he had multiple failsafes in place when Batou and Togusa visited. It's certainly not the Yakuza.